# How can I append a code to <head> using PHP?

Tags: php, html, append, head

I've got a little web project where all pages have a common header file they import before the actual page content. The header file is something like the following:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/some_script.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/web.ico" />
</head>
```

Then all the pages have a `<?php include("header.php"); ?>`, so they load the `<head>` tags at the begining.

I'm now coding a new page, that also includes the previous `header.php`, but it requires a second javascript to load. I can load it without issues using the `<script>` tag in the middle of the page, but I was wondering if its possible to append it directly to the `<head>` tag, instead of resting in the middle of the html code.

The actual code looks like something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/some_script.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/web.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Some text here</p>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/another_script.js"></script>
        <p>Some more text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I would like to know how to achieve the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/some_script.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/web.ico" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/another_script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Some text here</p>
        <p>Some more text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know this is possible using for example [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or the [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), but I was wondering if I can achieve this without using any other external source.

Comment: One solution would be to make a change to the `header.php` file, and have something like `if (page === "blah.php"` then include `another_script.js`. Providing there's only a couple of pages that require different scripts, as the logic could get quite long.

Comment: I think that for a small project (like the one I'm doing), that is the simplest solution. @NickR , could you please expand the idea as a possible answer?

Answer (score 6):

You may include **header.php** like this:

```
<?php 

ob_start();
include("header.php"); 
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo str_replace('</head>', '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/another_script.js"></script></head>', $contents)

?>
```

Code is simple. You get contents of header.php to buffer, than add before of `</head>` new script include and print this new content to browser.

Comment: Is this what you need?

Comment: How is it possible to call that str_replace from another included file?The head is appended in the mid of the body if I call it there. Is it possible to add this to the head before body?

Comment: @m1crdy it's difficult to understand what are you trying to do. I think you should create a new question with some more description of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Something we did for this was to put our drawing into a class and then have that class do all the output. So you could write a class like this and call a method to add things to the headers. Then it would get output all at once. Here's some pseudo code to give you a push in that direction. This way, your includes can call the `addHeader` function and add in any extra files you need before you move to output. In other words, this is essentially a controller for your view.

```
class Draw {
    protected headers = array();

    public function addHeader($header) {
         $this->headers[] = $header;
    }

    public function drawPage($page) {
        $headers = $this->headers;
        include 'top.php';
        include $page . '.php';
        include 'bottom.php';
    }
}
```